# Removable singularities of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

So, I'm a little confused about removable singularities.  Consider the function below:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^{2/3}}$$

Obviously, we have isolated singularities at the points $z =  \pm i$.  However, are they removable?  In my studies, I have found that removable singularities exist if the following are true:

- the limit of $(z-z_o)f(z)$ as $z$ approaches $z_o$ is zero.
- the limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches $z_o$ exists.

I have deduced that the first limit above is, indeed, equal to zero.  So, can I deduce that the singularity is removable?  I ask because wolfram alpha says that I have a pole at these points, not a removable singularity.  Further, when I ask for a series about $z=i$, it has a $(z-i)^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ term.  What's going on here; it seems like derived results are contradicting each other?

Comment: Since you have a power with non-integral exponent, these are not isolated singularities. You have a branch cut connecting the two zeros of $1+z^2$ (either passing through $\infty$ or not). They are neither removable singularities nor poles, they are branch points.

Comment: Ahhhh....so, since there is a branch point at i and -i, there is not a deleted neighborhood/disk around z=i or z=-i which is analytic (the branch forces the value to change and prevents analyticity).  Thus, they can not be isolated singularities?  Is that the proper way to think about it?

Comment: Right. If you go around one of the branch points analytically continuing the function, you must go around the branch point thrice to get back where you started.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize: before we can *remove* a singularity, we must *isolate* it first: that is, make sure that the function is holomorphic in some annulus $\{z:0<|z-z_0|<r\}$. Which isn't the case here, because starting with some branch of $f$ and traveling around $z_0$  in a circle, we observe $\arg f $ changing by $4\pi/3$.

The asymptotic behavior of $f$ near $z_0$ does not even come into play.